# Reducir tamaño del campo en el SQL SERVER

Tags: sql

me gustaría reducir el tamaño de un campo en el SQL SERVER, cómo hago?
Por ejemplo, el campo al que me estoy refiriendo se llama Observación y eso me trae 2 tipos: "express" y "domicilio", me gustaría reducirlo a 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O bien lo haces con el SQL Management Studio o bien mediante sentencia SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype;
```

En tu caso seria algo así, a falta de conocer exactamente el tipo de datos y nombre de los objetos

```
ALTER TABLE TuNombreDeTable
ALTER COLUMN Observacion varchar(12);
```

Comment: Ojo que si hay data con más de 12 caracteres esto va a lanzar error